# How do I guard a worker or settler in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ V you can't have two military units on top of each other, but it's ok to have a military unit in the same hex as a worker or settler to guard them. The thing is, I have to move the settler and the military unit separately and make sure they end up on the same hex every turn. Is there a way to automatically group them together, so that I don't accidentally leave my settler or worker unguarded?

Comment: I was running into this with a great general as well, since they need to be near the front lines but you have to make sure they aren't left unprotected.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have read all of the relevant sections of the CIV 5 manual in PDF form. I have experimented with every possible button in the user interface while military units are in the same hex as settlers/workers. There does not appear to be a way to automatically group the units together for defense. You have to do it manually, at least for now. Hopefully this will change with patches, or at least a mod.

Comment: The fact that nobody has answered also leads me to believe that there isn't a way to do it. In another day or two, I'll assume I am correct.

Comment: Your best bet is generally to post units just outside the border your worker is working inside of. Early detection and interception beats guarding.

Answer (score 3):

There is one way that works when *moving* a civilian unit a great distance, such as a settler moving to a new place.

Start with your worker and your military unit in the same hex, with the same number of movement points. Then you can assign each unit to move to the same target hex, and they will take the same path there.

This will only work if the two units move the same *way*, such as a standard melee unit (2 moves/turn) and a standard settler (2 moves/turn). If the melee unit is an upgraded scout, or otherwise has a different way of moving, then the two units will become separated. This can also happen if there's anything in the way that would block one of the units, but not the other. (Such as an allied military unit that your civilian can't move through. Or if your pair of units would end their turn on a hex with a worker on it, then the civilian will stop elsewhere for the turn and your pair of moving units will forever be separated.)

This way of moving is unreliable, given the number of ways it can fail, but if you care about ease-of-use more than you care about reliability, it'll do for now.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't getting more up votes. It is the only thing that is closest to a solution so far and is what I do to manage this.

Comment: @Enigma Because the OP basically said that they already do this.

Comment: OP was talking about moving units manually every turn. My solution means that, for long moves, you only have to give the move command twice.